# How does Javascript differentiate between Json Objects and String?

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

I was reading a code snippet and figuring out how it works when this weird javascript problem came up.

In their javascript they called

```
var apiUrl = '/api/v1/pin/?format=json&order_by=-id&offset='+String(offset);
...
$.get(apiUrl, function(pins) { 
    for (...; i < pins.objects.length; i++) ... // works fine
});
```

their api returns this json format:

```
{"meta": {"limit": 50, "next": "?limit=50&format=json&order_by=-id&offset=60", "offset":    
10, "previous": null, "total_count": 79}, "objects": [ {...},{...}, ... ]}
```

I tried to mimic it but the $.get never accepted my simplified json string.

```
// my attempt
$.get(myApiUrl, function(pins) { 
    for (...; i < pins.objects.length; i++) ... // ERROR: undefined length
});
```

My Json string is in the similar but shortened format.

```
{"objects": [{...},{...}, ... ]}
```

I couldn't get it to work until I googled the $.getJson() command. I am just wondering why their javascript code works with just $.get whereas mine has to use $.getJson??

Is it some kind of header you can set to force javascript to read it as json?

Comment: response-type application/json maybe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't specify content type explicitly jQuery will try to determine data type based on headers returned by server.

If you are not using JSON serializers, then verify validity of your JSON using http://jsonlint.com/ or [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isPlainObject/), otherwise you will get an error.

Correct ContentType header for JSON is: `application/json`

Comment: Thank you, you were correct. My issue was resolved after setting the correct headers.

Answer (score 3):

In both cases the AJAX call returns a string. `jQuery` somehow has to figure out what to do with it. How it does that depends on the `dataType` option.

The docs call the default value `Intelligent guess`. So how to guess? Evaluating the `Content-Type` header of the response. If it's `application/json`then `jQuery`will try to create an object.

To ensure that `jQuery`will always try to interpret the response as `JSON` you can set the `dataType` to `json`.

Answer (score 2):

Set the HTTP response header `Content-Type` to `application/json`

Eg:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
```